# SQL: Take data from 3 records and combine to one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has three records per day, for 3 shift segments. I am trying combine the records into one row per day.

Data currently looks like this:

```
ID    DayNum    Flag    SesNum    SesType    SesStart    SesEnd

1       1        Y        1         Reg       06:15       10:15
1       1        Y        2         Brk       10:15       11:15
1       1        Y        3         Reg       11:15       15:15
1       2        Y        1         Reg       05:00       11:00
1       2        Y        2         Brk       11:00       12:00
1       2        Y        3         Reg       12:00       15:00
```

I needit to take the three segments in each day and combine them into one record. So one line for each day in each ID containing the three segments. I would like it to look like this:

```
ID    DayNum   Flag   S1_Type    S1_Start    S1_End    S2_Type    S2_Start    S2_End    S3_Type    S3_Start   S3_End

1       1       Y       Reg        06:15       10:15     Brk        10:15       11:15     Reg        11:15      15:15
```

I have tried the following, and it's almost there:

```
Select *

FROM (

select 

a.WorkPatternID,
a.DayNo,
max(a.WorkedFlag) as 'WorkedFlag',
max(a.SessionType) as 'S1_Type',
max(a.SessionStart) as 'S1_Start',
max(a.SessionEnd) as 'S1_End',
max(b.SessionType) as 'S2_Type',
max(b.SessionStart) as 'S2_Start',
max(b.SessionEnd) as 'S2_End',
max(c.SessionType) as 'S3_Type',
max(c.SessionStart) as 'S3_Start',
max(c.SessionEnd) as 'S3_End'

FROM (  Select * 
        FROM WP_Patterns
        WHERE SessionNo = 1 ) a

Inner JOIN (    select * 
        FROM WP_Patterns
        WHERE SessionNo = 2 ) b
ON a.WorkPatternID = b.WorkPatternID

Inner JOIN (    select * 
        FROM WP_Patterns
        WHERE SessionNo = 3 ) c
ON a.WorkPatternID = c.WorkPatternID

GROUP BY a.WorkPatternID, a.DayNo

) t

WHERE WorkedFlag = 'Y'
```

However I think the max functions are ignoring the day in S2 and S3, and therefore returning the max time found on all days, which is not what I need.

Any help on cleaning this mess up would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, daynum, max(flag),
       max(case when sesnum = 1 then SessionType end) as s1_sessionType,
       max(case when sesnum = 1 then SessionStart end) as s1_ SessionStart,
       max(case when sesnum = 2 then SessionType end) as s2_sessionType,
       max(case when sesnum = 2 then SessionStart end) as s2_ SessionStart,
       max(case when sesnum = 3 then SessionType end) as s3_sessionType,
       max(case when sesnum = 3 then SessionStart end) as s3_ SessionStart
from WP_Patterns
group by id, daynum;
```